# WPF Label and TextBlock show DateTime in different format

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I develop some application. And I've found some strange things related to the DateTime format. So I've created some test application to check it in more detail.
So, my test application has the next structure:

1. Custom object class with only Date property:

   ```
   public class MyObject
   {
       public DateTime Date { get; private set; }

       public MyObject(DateTime date)
       {
           Date = date;
       }
   }
   ```

2. Custom ViewModel class:

   ```
   public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
           public virtual ICollectionView TableView
           {
                   get => tableView;
                   set
                   {
                           tableView = value;
                           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TableView));
                   }
           }

           public virtual ObservableCollection<MyObject> TableItems
           {
                   get { return tableItems; }
                   set
                   {
                           tableItems = value;
                           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TableItems));

                           TableView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(tableItems);
                   }
           }

           public MyViewModel()
           {
                   var dateTimes = new List<MyObject>() 
                   {
                           new MyObject(DateTime.MinValue),
                           new MyObject(DateTime.Now),
                           new MyObject(DateTime.MaxValue)
                   };

                   TableItems = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>(dateTimes);
           }

           private ICollectionView tableView;
           private ObservableCollection<MyObject> tableItems;

           public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

           public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
           {
                   if (PropertyChanged != null)
                            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
           }
   }
   ```
3. View control with DataGrid and ListView. Both of them have a binding to the same TableView collection:

   ```
   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TableView}">
      </DataGrid>
      <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TableView}">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                  <CheckBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                      <CheckBox.Content>
                          <Label Content="{Binding Date}"/>
                      </CheckBox.Content>
                  </CheckBox>
              </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
   </Grid>
   ```

In this case I see a different view of the date in the table and in the list:

[image]

In case when I change the Label to the TextBlock in the ListView item template I will see the same result:

[image]

Why did it happen? And how can I display the same format in all controls according to the Culture date-time settings?

Comment: Dates start at 1/1/01 which is the MIN.  Since you did not initialize the MIN you are getting 1/1/01.   The same for MAX which is 12/31/9999.  To get a different format use ToString("d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt").

Comment: Your `TableItems` setter has an infinite-recursive-loop (the setter calls itself). Generally speaking, collection properties should not have setters at all: instead of outright replacing the `ObservableCollection<T>` your code should add/remove items from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `ContentControl` (and therefore `Label` too) uses the `ContentControl.ContentStringFormat` property to format `string` content, the text elements like `TextBlock` or `TextBox` use the `FrameworkElement.Language` property, which defaults to `"en-US"`.

### `ContentControl` (and `Label`)

In case of the `ContentControl`, where `ContentControl.ContentStringFormat` is not explicitly defined, the `string` is formatted using the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` as fallback `CultureInfo` (using the `DateTimeFormatInfo` returned from the `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat` property).
In your case this is obviously not the language "en-US".

If you want to enforce a common date format on particular `ContentControl` elements, you can use a named `Style` to set `ContentControl.ContentStringFormat` property. To set the date format globally , you can set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` property:

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
class App : Application
{
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnStartup(e);
    var globalCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");

    /* Consider to set the CultureInfo.DefaultThread properties too */

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = globalCultureInfo;
    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = globalCultureInfo;
  }
}
```

If you don't want to change the thread culture, you can use an implicit `Style` that targets `ContentControl` and define it in *App.xaml*:

```xml
<Style TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat"
          Value="dd.MM.yyyy" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Label" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}" />
```

### `TextBlock` and `TextBox`

For text elements you have to set or bind the `FrameworkElement.Language` property, for example using an implicit `Style` defined in *App.xaml* to apply the language globally:

```xml
<Style TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Setter Property="Language"
          Value="en-GB" />
</Style>
```

Alternatively, you can set the `Binding.StringFormat` property or use a `IValueConverter`. But both solutions are not helpful if you need to configure the date format globally.

### `FrameworkElement` (`ContentControl` and `TextBlock` etc.)

To set the language for all `FrameworkElement` types, you must override the `FrameworkElement.Language` property in order to override the default value (which is `"en-US"`):

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
class App : Application
{
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnStartup(e);
    var globalCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");

    /* Consider to set the Thread.CurrentThread 
       and CultureInfo.DefaultThread properties too */
   
    XmlLanguage defaultFrameworkLanguage = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(globalCultureInfo.Name);
    FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
      typeof(FrameworkElement),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(defaultFrameworkLanguage)); 
  }
}
```